# Getting files from dropbox

Tags: software-installation, kernel

I am downloading files from dropbox to my raspberry pi. Now my first problem is, I have no idea how to download dropbox for my raspberry, On Ubuntu it's easy but on my raspberry it wont work. So I am downloading my files from the dropbox website. Which turns it into a zip all of the sudden for me. I have no idea how to unzip the file. I have tried:

```
unzip /home/pi/file.zip /home/pi/directory
```

but it says the file isnt a zip file. So my problems are:

1.I dont know how to download dropbox(Dont even know if this is possible)

2.I dont know how to unzip

Can someone help me with these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont know how to download dropbox(Dont even know if this is possible)

You don't mention your pi distro so I'll assume raspbian or some other debian wheezy variant. There's no dropbox in the raspbian repo -- perhaps because there might actually be no dropbox in the normal debian repos either.

You can't use the .deb package from the Dropbox site because it was not compiled for the pi's oddball processor, but you can [build it from source](https://www.dropbox.com/help/247/en).  But don't bother: after that, you still need to install the "proprietary deamon" online the first time you run it.  That fails with "platform not supported" :(

Since the deamon is not open source, the only way around this is for Dropbox to compile a version for the pi.

Comment: So just using my HDD for file transfering would be the easiest?

Comment: and yes Raspbian

Comment: There's only 2 million of them, why would they bother? sigh

Comment: There's lots of ways to implement file sharing, that's a whole question in itself. @JohnLaRooy : Find a dropbox dev and send them one for xmas, lol...I don't think it would be much stress for them to do this, if someone were interested in doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox uploader and drop-shell are very good bash scripts that work well on the pi.

https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the message that it isn't a zip file is because the command is trying to unzip both arguments. It looks like you actually want to direct output to the second argument.

The format for `unzip` is:

```
unzip [-Z] [-cflptTuvz[abjnoqsCDKLMUVWX$/:^]] file[.zip] [file(s) ...] [-x xfile(s) ...] [-d exdir]
```

So if you want to specify a directory to extract *to*, use the `-d` flag:

```
unzip /home/pi/file.zip -d /home/pi/directory
```

For more info, see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not use Dropbox (the program) on a Raspberry Pi, since the Pi uses a ARM-architecture CPU, and Dropbox only supports the x86-architecture (found in any Intel or AMD CPU).
2. You can, however, download a zip-fil from dropbox.com, and unpack it. Move the zip-fil to the directory you want to unpack it, then run `unzip <zipfile>` or specify where to extract it with `unzip <zipfile> -d <targetdir>`

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox doesn't provide client for Raspberry Pi (as well as for other ARM) but you can use ExaGear Desktop emulator to run original x86 linux dropbox client

1. Install ExaGear Desktop, which allow to run x86 software on Raspberry (note that ExaGear isn't free and you have to obtain the license)

   ```
   tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi2.tar.gz
   sudo ./install-exagear.sh ubuntu-1404
   ```
2. Run ExaGear

   ```
   exagear
   ```
3. Download Dropbox x86 client

   ```
   wget linux.dropbox.com/packages/debian/dropbox_2015.10.28_i386.deb
   ```
4. Install Dropbox

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i dropbox_2015.10.28_i386.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
5. Create directory required by Dropbox

   ```
   sudo mkdir /usr/share/X11/xkb
   ```
6. Now you can run Dropbox from Start Menu and your files will be automatically synced

[image]

Instruction is based on [this post](https://eltechs.com/run-dropbox-on-raspberry-pi/)